# Cesàro theorem in probability

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory

Let :

- $(X_k)_{k \geq 1}$ independant and same law
- $EX_1=0$ and $Var(X_1)=1$
- $S_k= \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$
- $U_n(\alpha)= \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}}$
- $T_n(\alpha)= \frac{1}{n^{\alpha}} \sum_{k=1}^{n} S_k$

1. If $\alpha > \frac{1}{2}$ what is the convergence in probability of $U_n(\alpha)$ ?
2. If $\alpha > \frac{3}{2}$ what is the convergence in probability of $T_n(\alpha)$ ?

---

My attempt :
$\epsilon >0$
$\overline{X_n} \to 0$ in probability et $ \sqrt{n}\overline{X_n} \to N(0,1)$ by CLT

$\dfrac{1}{ n^{\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon} } S_n =\dfrac{   n^{\frac{1}{2} } \overline{X_n}         }{ n^ {\epsilon} }  \to 0$ in probability.

$\epsilon >0$

$\begin{align*}
T_n(\frac{3}{2} + \epsilon ) &= \dfrac{1}{  n^{\frac{3}{2} + \epsilon }   }    \sum_{k=1}^{n} S_k\\
                                           &= \dfrac{1}{  n^{\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon }   }  \frac{   \sum_{k=1}^{n} S_k } { n} \\
                                            &=  \dfrac{1}{  n^{\frac{1}{2} + \epsilon }   } (S_n + o(1)  ) \\
                                           & \to 0 \\
\end{align*}
$

I use Cesàro theorem for a real sequence $v_n$: $v_n \to l \Rightarrow \overline{v_n} \to l$.
Can we use such theorem in this context of convergence in probability ?